# Why the Task.Run give errors?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to follow this tutorial video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ae1_6ELGVYw

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private Task ProcessData(List<string> list, IProgress<ProgressReport> progress)
        {
            int index = 1;
            int totalProcess = list.Count;
            var progressReport = new ProgressReport();

            return Task.Run()) => 
            {


            });
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                list.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            lblStatus.Text = "Working...";
            var progress = new Progress<ProgressReport>();
            progress.ProgressChanged += (o, report) =>
            {
                lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Processing...{0}%", report.PercentComplete);
                progressBar.Value = report.PercentComplete;
                progressBar.Update();
            };

            await ProcessData(list, progress);
            lblStatus.Text = "Done !";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using visual studio 2019 and project target .NET Framework 4.7.2

I'm getting error on the Run :

No overload for method 'Run' takes 0 arguments

but in the video Task.Run is empty without errors.

And error on the closing : });

} Expected

Comment: `())` should be `(()`.

Comment: @mjwills Right, my embarrassing mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code you got mixed up with the parenthesis here:

```
 return Task.Run(() =>  // should be () => {}
            {


            });
```

What this syntax means is that `() => {}` is a `Action` delegate which `Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value.` (see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netcore-3.1)

In C# you can declare and pass them as variables, e.g.

```
var myFunc = () => { Console.WriteLine("test"); };

Task.Run(myFunc);
```

Comment: `() => {}` isn't a `Func` or a function. It's a lambda expression that represents an `Action` or a subroutine.

Comment: @Enigmativity well spotted, it is actually an `Action`